# What is the equivalent of sqlite3's sqlite3_exec in cppsqlite3 (if there is any)?

Tags: c++, c, unicode, sqlite, cppsqlite

I am using CppSQLite3 as a wrapper of sqlite3 because it allows passing UNICODE strings and because it supports UNICODE in general. 
Is there an CppSQLite3 function which is similar to sqlite3_exec() in the sense of allowing passing a callback function?

sqlite3_exe is declared as follow:

```
SQLITE_API int sqlite3_exec(
        sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
        const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
        int(*callback)(void*, int, char**, char**),  /* Callback function */
        void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
        char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
        );
```

CppSQLite3's execQuery() is declared as follow:

```
CppSQLite3Query execQuery(LPCTSTR szSQL);
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching through the [source code](https://github.com/neosmart/CppSQLite/blob/master/CppSQLite3.cpp) shows that `sqlite3_exec()` is called only from here:

```
int CppSQLite3DB::execDML(const char* szSQL);
```

But the callback is not supported; if you want to read returned data, you must use the query object.

Comment: Can you give an example for using a callback function?

Comment: No, because the callback is not supported in CppSQLite3.